# Greasemonkey script: get matched include rule

Tags: javascript, url, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script with a few `@include` rules. I'd like to know exactly which one was matched, because the script has to behave slightly differently depending on the URL.

Is there a way to find this out through Greasemonkey's API? I know I can get this information through DOM, but I'm hoping Greasemonkey's API provides something like that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greasemonkey does not tell a script which rule it matched. 
Instead, your script can test [properties of the `window.location` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).  EG:

```
if (/stackoverflow\.com/i.test (location.hostname) ) {
    alert ("Yay!");
}
else if (/quora\.com/i.test (location.hostname) ) {
    alert ("Uh oh!");
}
```

---

---

If you really wanted to, you could loop through the `includes` and `matches` arrays of [the `GM_info` object](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_info), and try to determine which one(s) would fire on the current `location`, but that's not foolproof and there's zero need for it (except, maybe, an over-zealous code review of the script).